# Linear independence with a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given the following vectors $v_1 = (k,0,1),\quad v_2=(2,1-k,2),\quad v_3 = (1,2,-k)$

The objective is to find for which $k\in\mathbb{R}$ means the vectors are valid basis vectors.

- *For this I know they have to be linear independent and that means no vector can be a linear combination of the other two vectors.*

Gaussian elimination gives:
$$\begin{vmatrix} k & 2 & 1\\ 0 & 1- k & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & -k\\\end{vmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 2-2k & 1+k^2\\ 0 & 1- k & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & -k\\\end{vmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 2-2k & 1+k^2\\ 0 & 2-2k & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & -k\\\end{vmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 2-2k & 1+k^2\\ 0 & 0 & 3-k^2 \\ 1 & 2 & -k\\\end{vmatrix}
$$

Comment: I guess your first equations are not correct.
Start this way: $$\lambda_1 v_1+ \lambda_2 v_2 + \lambda_3 v_3 = (0,0,0),$$ use gaussian elimination
and try to see when the above system has a unique solution $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3) = (0,0,0)$.

Comment: Can you show how exactly you reached the first system?

Comment: Sure. If for example $v_1=(a,b,c)$ I multiplied $\lambda_1$ with $a$, $\lambda_2$ with $b$, and $\lambda_3$ with $c$, I sum them and equal to zero. Then I do the same for $v_2$, and $v_3$. Is this perhaps not correct?

Comment: Yeap. It is not correct. The 3 equations will be derived from the first equation in my first comment.

Comment: @thanasissdr I updated the post now. It seems like I can figure out the values $k=\pm\sqrt{3} \land k = 1$ now :). Thank you so much for your help! Appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a comment:

The equation $$\lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2 + \lambda_3 v_3 = (0,0,0)$$ yields:

$\begin{array}[t]{l}
\lambda_1 \cdot(k,0,1) + \lambda_2 \cdot (2,1-k,2) + \lambda_3 \cdot(1,2,-k)= (0,0,0)\\
(\color{red}{k\lambda_1} ,\color{blue}{0}, \lambda_1 ) + (\color{red}{2\lambda_2} ,\color{blue}{(1-k)\lambda_2},2\lambda_2) + (\color{red}{\lambda_3},\color{blue}{ 2\lambda_3}, -k\lambda_3) = (\color{red}{0},\color{blue}{0},0)
\end{array} $

Thus, we take the $3\times 3$ system:

$$\begin{array}[t]{l}
k\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 0 \\
0\cdot \lambda_1 + (1-k)\lambda_2 + 2 \lambda_3 = 0  \\
\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 - k\lambda_3 = 0 
\end{array}$$

with variables $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ and parameter $k$. I think you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Your vector space is probably $\mathbb R^3$. The following condition needs to be satisfied.

$$p(k) = \begin{vmatrix} k & 0 & 1\\ 2 & 1- k & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & - k \end{vmatrix}\neq 0 $$

Apparently, $p(k)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $3$. It is sufficient to find its roots.

It seems to be that $$p(k) = k^3 - k^2-3k + 3.$$

It is quite easy to evaluate the roots.

Comment: How did you translate that into a polynomial?

Comment: Try to evaluate the $3\times 3$ determinant.

Comment: Ah, way ahead of what I have learned at the moment then. Thank you so much for your help, I will have to figure this out in a more elementary way.